# Symfony editing admin views

Tags: php, symfony1, admin, backend

I work on existing symfony project and I want to change something in view in admin (backend app) which is automatically generated. I found that I can change views in `/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/data/generator/sfDoctrineModule/admin/template/templates/...`

I think it is not good idea to edit this files. How can I change these templates?

Answer (score 2):

You can override the template at the module level. After visiting the page in question look in the cache directory and check out the autogenerated code there for example:

```
cache/
  backend/
    modules/
      /autoMyModule/
        templates/
```

You can then figure out which file it is you need to change and then create that file in `apps/backend/myModule/templates` and override what you need.

Comment: Is it possible to make it for all modules at once? Maybe there is possibility to override whole plugin?

Comment: Well you could you make your own generator theme/templates, but thats pretty complex unless the changes are pretty big. What are you trying to change? There is probably a less complex but still DRY solution.

Comment: I want to move actions buttons from the bottom of all lists to the top.